# Content not being showed correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I do not know what is going on with my application. I already cleared server cache, browser cache, I think I already cleared all the cache possible.

I am running my ruby on rails application in linux distribution, but the content not always appears correctly. For instance, I go to the page and I see this:

[image]

Basically it does not care about some of the page information like if user is logged in or not. But if I click F5 to refresh the page it shows up correctly:

[image]
Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: this may be a controversial suggestion, but try disabling turbolinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible this error is connected with js libraries, that you use. If you want simple solution, you can try remove turoblinks, **but this can make your app slow**.

if you can remove turoblinks:

1. Remove the gem 'turbolinks' line from your Gemfile.
2. Remove the //= require turbolinks from your
       app/assets/javascripts/application.js.
3. Remove the two "data-turbolinks-track" => true 
       from your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.

Comment: will give it a try